# Log yum update checks even when there are no packages available for update?

Tags: yum, rsyslog

I need to ingest events for nightly yum update checks (using yum-cron) into a SIEM.  Unfortunately yum only logs events to yum.log when action is taken, for example updates or installations.  There is no event logged when you check for updates and there are none available.  Auditors have also specified that ingesting events proving yum-cron ran is not enough so I can't just import the events from the cron log.

I could run a script that runs yum check-update and pipe the output to a file, then have rsyslog ingest lines from that file but that is messy and not ideal.  I also want it to be as easy to configure as possible as it will have to be scripted to be able to configure it on new instances quickly.

It is also a special distribution from a vendor and the logger command does not work with rsyslog on the distribution.

Is there an easy way to track, via log, the fact that yum did run and that no packages were found for update?  Indicating that all packages are up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another forum got me started down the path to a solution and this was what I ended up doing to resolve the issue:

yum-cron supports email notifications, unfortunately the SIEM we are using does not ingest events via email.  However looking through the yum-cron scripts they redirect output to a temporary file which they then use to email notifications.  I ended up editing the /etc/cron.daily/0yum.cron script to redirect output to /var/log/yum.log instead by changing:

```
} >> $YUMTMP 2>&1
```

to:

```
} >> /var/log/yum.log 2>&1
```

I then used the im_file module of rsyslog to ingest the yum.log and forward it to the SIEM.